# Ubuntu won't boot after installing Windows 10 on separate ssd

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

So I have an encrypted Ubuntu installation on an M.2 ssd on my desktop that I have been using as my main device, I recently obtained a second SSD and I installed Windows 10 onto it so I could have a duel booted PC. But now I cannot boot into my Ubuntu drive, when I try I get a windows recovery screen. I am thinking that maybe the grub boot loader got corrupted. Would I be able to use the boot recovery tool to reinstall grub on this drive or would I have to manually re-install grub? This is the first time I have dealt with an issue like this so I am not sure what to do if I have to manually re-install grub.

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair%20& 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ If encrypted be sure to decrypt install before running the report. Are both installs UEFI boot on gpt partitioned drives? Report will show that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Bootloaders have the tendency to write to the first disk. So when you want to install another system on another disk the bootloader writes to the first disk anyway. 
The solution I use is disconnect the first disk and then do an install. If you have a computer with watercooling and hard tubing that might be a problem though. 
What you can do:
1 )Install `grub2` again, using the usb stick/device you used to install `Ubuntu`.
2 ) Install `Grub2Win` on your `Windows` installation and make it your default bootloader. And add Ubuntu to the menu/configuration. ( Some hardcore Linux users say that this program is sh#t, but I never had a problem with it.

Comment: Would Grub2Win work on a luks partition?

Comment: It is a bootloader. So I think ( do not know for sure because I don't have experience with luks partitions ) if the partition is bootable, you should be able to configure that. I have configured Kubuntu, Mint and multiple .iso files and of course Win10. You can give it try.